# Best approach to doing analysis of sets of tags?

Tags: python, sql, excel, ms-access

I have thousands of survey responses that have been tagged according to the content of the response. Each response can have one tag or many (up to 20), and the tags are independent of one another rather than being structured into category-subcategory or something.

I want to be able to do analysis like the following:

- How many instances of a given tag are there?
- Which tags occur most frequently overall?
- Where tag X is present, which other tags appear along with it most frequently?
- List of all tags with the count of each next to it
- Select subsets of the data to do similar analysis on (by country, for example)

The people I'm working with have traditionally tackled everything in Excel (general business strategy consulting work), and that won't work in this case. Their response is to change the project framework to something that Excel can handle in a pivot table, but it would be so much better if we could use more robust tools that allow for more sophisticated relationships.

I've been learning SQLite but am starting to fear that the kinds of things I want to do will be pretty complicated.

I've also been learning Python (for unrelated reasons) and am kind of wondering if an ORM tool and some Python code might be the better way to go.

And then there's something like Access (which I don't have but would possibly be willing to get if it's a sweet spot for this kind of thing).

In summary, I'd love to know how hard these kinds of analysis would be to do overall and which tools would best be suited for the job. I'm completely open to the idea that I'm thinking about some of or all of the problem in a way that's backwards and would welcome any advice on any aspect of what I've written here.

Comment: Ideally the analysis will be done periodically, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Collect all tags into a list and use the python collections.Counter and associated methods to get the frequencies and a host of other statistics. Just like this

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> x=['java', 'python', 'scheme', 'scheme', 'scheme', 'python', 'go', 'go', 'c',
... 'c']
>>> freqs = Counter(x)
>>> freqs.most_common(1)
[('scheme', 3)]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

While data concerning the frequency of individual tags should be very simple to construct, data concerning the relationships between tags is very difficult and falls under the realm of data mining.  Here is what I would do, at a very high level, assuming you have a response table, a tag table, and a response_tag table.

Create a summary table that lists each unique combination of response tags, along with a column that will indicate how many times this combination occurs.  The table structure should be something like `combination (id, count)`, `combination_tags(combination_id, tag_id)`.  Use a procedural statement (ORM or SQL Cursors) to populate the table, and then use ad-hoc queries to sample the data.

This is not a simple operation, but it will get you results using a simple RDBMS, without having to use enterprise level data mining solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a quite small dataset, so you do not need any kind of ORM really, just load all data in Python and chew a report of it.

SQL as a language is horrible for a more complex data analysis (e.g. where you really want to crosstabulate things etc).

Answer (score 0):

Go with SQL!  It is very powerful for data analysis.  It will allow you to ask questions in the future about the data.  Questions that you have not yet thought of.

Although SQL as a language may seem a bit cumbersome, it is much easier to use than a "real" programming language.  In your case, SQL interfaces to Excel, so users can get access to the data through a tool they are familiar with.

If you do go with SQL, a real database (SQLLite) is a better solution than MSAccess.

I feel strongly enough in SQL as an analysis tool that I wrote a book on the subject, "Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel".  You might check out the Amazon comments (http://www.amazon.com/Data-Analysis-Using-SQL-Excel/dp/0470099518/ref=pd_sim_b_1) to understand how effective it can be.